# NextJS adding comment tags around dynamic page title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS 12 .. I have a Layout.js file which has the following;

```
import Head from "next/head";

const Layout = ({children, pageTitle, mainClass}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>Website :: {pageTitle}</title>
            </Head>
            ........
```

In my `index.js` i have the following to render the Layout component;

```
<Layout pageTitle="Home">
```

When it renders in the browser, the pageTitle gets surrounded by comment code for some reason, it looks like so;

```
<title>Website :: <!-- -->Home<!-- --></title>
```

I cant figure out how to get rid of the comment code, is this a bug?

Comment: can you try it in a different browser

Comment: Does the same thing in Firefox / Safari / Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[from this github post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35870#issuecomment-1087516255)

> Can you try to encode the whole title with jsx? As above issue
> mentioned, comments are injected intentionally as new constraints for
> streaming rendering, so if you want to keep it as a single string
> maybe wrap them together as a jsx child to avoid generating comments

```
<title>{`Website :: ${pageTitle}`}</title>
```